# How should I calculate p times of f(x)?

Tags: ocaml

I want to calculate `f(..f(x))` `p` times. The following is my code.

```
let rec function f x p = if p = 0 then x else function f (f x) p-1;;
```

I wonder how I should make it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very close, but your code has syntax errors that are going to make it hard to make progress. I think the main problem is that you're using `function` as an identifier, but it is a keyword in OCaml. If you change to `myfun`, things should start working quite a bit better.

You also need to watch your precedences. The following code:

```
f a b-1
```

is parsed like this:

```
(f a b) - 1
```

not like this:

```
f a (b - 1)
```

You need to write the parentheses explicitly to get this second parse.

Comment: You are great! The problems you pointed out are unnoticeable to a novice in OCaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a recursive function `ch` to apply a function `f` many times (Church numeral??) as follows:

```
let rec ch f p x = if p = 0 then x else f (ch f  (p-1) x);;
```

The problems in your original code are that:

1. need to name the function as something, such as `ch` here.
2. need to call the same function `ch` to get the recursion going as shown above. In your original code, there is no recursion.

Example

```
let p1 x = x + 1 ;;

ch p1 3 1 ;;
```

this will give you

```
- : int = 3
```

as intended.